# Tikz - Overlapping nodes in binomial tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, automata

I am new to Tikz, and I want to draw a binomial tree with the tikz libary automata. Other questions suggested the use of the library positioning, and to use the syntax right=of (node) instead of right of=node.
I get the following tree, (node 5 and 6 overlap). Is there an easy way to move node 5 automatically a little bit to the left and node 6 to the right, without messing with distances and other parameters? (Because the solution should scale).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=40mm,semithick, state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
\node[state, label={$\tilde{S}^1$}](1){1};
\node[state](2)[below left=of 1] {2};
\node[state](3)[below right=of 1] {3};

\node[state](4)[below left=of 2] {4};
\node[state](5)[below right=of 2] {5};
\node[state](6)[below left=of 3] {6};
\node[state](7)[below right=of 3] {7};


\path[->] (1) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(2)
      ;
       
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing your tree with use of the `forest` package (which is dedicated for drawing trees), the code for tree become simpler and much shorter.

**Edit:** Considering OP request in comment, that some edges should have dash pattern.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    circle, draw, semithick,
    minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree
    l sep =12mm,
    s sep = 6mm,
/tikz/arr/.style = {draw=cyan!60, -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}, shorten >=1pt},
% for the case when you like to have
% all edges to bottom nodes dashed; 
% using this, remove next code line with edge = arr,
%if level = 1{edge=arr}{edge={arr, dashed}}, 
     edge = arr,
        },
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.5, node
              font=\footnotesize, text=blue, anchor=#1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
%%%% diagram body
[1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$
    [2, EL=1-p
        [4,edge=dashed]
        [5,edge=dashed]
    ]
    [3, EL=p
        [6]
        [7]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks very interesting. Is it also possible to make some arrows dashed?

Comment: @Tamar, of course. just add to node after this edge option `edge=dashed`. See edited answer.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your node distance is always the same, hence the overlap. I suggest you create your tree by using `child nodes` and set the `sibbling distance` for each level. That way you take control of your nodes positions.

[image: binomial tree in progress]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        auto,
        semithick,
        edge from parent/.style={draw=blue,-latex,shorten >=1pt},
        dashedge/.style={draw=blue,-latex,shorten >=1pt,dashed},
        state/.style={circle, draw=black, minimum size=1cm},
        level distance=3cm,
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
        
    \node[state, label={$\tilde{S}^1$}](ROOT){1}
        child   {node[state](1-1) {2}
                child {node[state](2-1){4} edge from parent[dashedge]} %<--- CHANGE HERE
                child {node[state](2-2){5} edge from parent[dashedge]} %<--- CHANGE HERE
                }
        child   {node[state](1-2) {3}
                child {node[state](2-3){6}}
                child {node[state](2-4){7}}
                };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And since you asked for having the possibility of scaling, you can see that there are only two parameters to change, so that you can parse them depending on your scaling.

#### EDIT

I added the possibility to draw different kinds of edges.

Comment: Thanks! I am always amazed how fast I can get an answer. Just one question: what does the 2-4 do when you introduce node 7?
But this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: These are just the node names (you named them (1) (2), (3)... in your MWE), in order to let you know exactly where you are, if you want to draw between them. You can change them or even delete them and just write your node contents like `child {node[state] {6}}` if you want.

Comment: Is there also an easy way to make some of the edges dashed? What would I need to add to make the edges from 2 -> 4 and 2->5 to be dashed, but the rest as it is?

Comment: I edited my post to give you that option.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot!